# Add image or text to border of rectangle or cluster - graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I have a code that allows me to perform a cluster. i want to move the label to the border of the cluster in the output. I have tried labelloc=l and other options but i am unable to make it work. attached is the one i got from graphviz while the other one is what i was expecting. is there a way to modify the code, add plugin or gvpr to get the desired output?

```
digraph AlignmentMap {
/*
/*
Author: Lars Barkman
Created: 2015-08-25
Changelog: See version control system

This is an example of an Alignment Map visualized with the help of Graphviz.
This solution depends on either generation or maintaining a .dot file and from that generating a image or document.
Personally, I think that editing the file by hand should be fine if the naming conventions used are intuitive.
Alignment maps first came to my attention on Martin Fowlers blog (http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AlignmentMap.html).
*/

// General layout of the graph
rankdir=LR; // Direction of the graph Left to Right
node [style="rounded,filled",color=black,shape=box,fillcolor=white]; // Defines the default layout of the nodes
graph [style=filled, splines=line]; // Fills the subgraphs and defines the layout of the connections
rank = same; // Makes sure that nodes are properly aligned even without a connection

// Column for Business Outcomes
subgraph cluster_business_outcome {
    label="Business Outcomes"
    graph [color=pink];

    business_outcome_Customer_Acquisition [label="Customer\nAcquisition"];
    business_outcome_Customer_Retention [label="Customer\nRetention"];
    business_outcome_Cost_of_Operations [label="Cost of\nOperations"];
}

// Column for IT Outcomes
subgraph cluster_IT_outcome {
    label=< <table>
        <tr><td fixedsize="true" width="50" height="50"><img src="./Azure-PlantUML-master/dist/Identity/AzureActiveDirectory.svg" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Active Directory</td></tr>
    </table>
>
    graph [color=mistyrose2];

    IT_outcome_Platform_Unbundling [label="Platform\nUnbundling"];
    IT_outcome_Site_Ux [label="Site Ux"];
    IT_outcome_Site_Performance [label="Site\nPerformance"];
    IT_outcome_Site_Scalability [label="Site\nScalability"];
}

// Column for IT Initiatives
subgraph cluster_IT_initiatives {
    label="IT Initiatives"
    graph [color=papayawhip];

    IT_initiatives_API [label="API"];
    IT_initiatives_Pluginize [label="Pluginize"];
    IT_initiatives_Responsive_Rewrite [label="Responsive\nRewrite"];
    IT_initiatives_Catalog_Performance [label="Catalog\nPerformance"];
    IT_initiatives_Sharding [label="Sharding"];
}

// Column for Action Items
subgraph cluster_action_items {
    label="Action Items"
    graph [color=darkseagreen1];

    action_items_0 [label="..."];
    action_items_1 [label="..."];
    action_items_App_X [label="App X"];
    action_items_Search_In_One [label="Search-\nIn-One"];
    action_items_4 [label="..."];
}

// Connections between nodes in the different columns
// business_outcome_* -> IT_outcome_Platform_*
business_outcome_Customer_Acquisition   -> IT_outcome_Platform_Unbundling;
business_outcome_Customer_Acquisition   -> IT_outcome_Site_Ux;
business_outcome_Customer_Retention     -> IT_outcome_Site_Ux;
business_outcome_Customer_Retention     -> IT_outcome_Site_Performance;
business_outcome_Cost_of_Operations     -> IT_outcome_Site_Performance;
business_outcome_Cost_of_Operations     -> IT_outcome_Site_Scalability;
// IT_outcome_* -> IT_initiatives_*
IT_outcome_Platform_Unbundling          -> IT_initiatives_API;
IT_outcome_Platform_Unbundling          -> IT_initiatives_Pluginize;
IT_outcome_Site_Ux                      -> IT_initiatives_Responsive_Rewrite;
IT_outcome_Site_Performance             -> IT_initiatives_Catalog_Performance;
IT_outcome_Site_Scalability             -> IT_initiatives_Sharding;
// IT_initiatives_* -> action_items_*
IT_initiatives_API                      -> action_items_0;
IT_initiatives_Pluginize                -> action_items_1;
IT_initiatives_Responsive_Rewrite       -> action_items_App_X;
IT_initiatives_Catalog_Performance      -> action_items_Search_In_One;
IT_initiatives_Sharding                 -> action_items_4;
```

}
[The one on right is graphviz and left is what i expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb1Pz.png)

Comment: It works for me on Linux.  What OS are you using , what version (dot -V), and what command line?

Comment: dot - graphviz version 2.43.0 (0) and ubuntu 20-04. But the key is i want the output to be on the one in left. notice the active directory overlaps the mistyrose2 container. can you confirm that your output is on the top left or border and not inside the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(sorry, I misunderstood the request)
Here is a gvpr "fix".

1. run `dot -Tdot` to position the nodes, edges, clusters
2. run that result through gvpr (program below) to remove the label and replace it with a (new) node
3. run that (modified) result through `neato -n2 -Tsvg` (see https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDottyWithCoords)

[note that I had to tweak the html to remove borders:]

```
 label=< <table BGCOLOR="transparent" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0">
       <tr><td fixedsize="true" width="50" height="50"><img src="image_dir/Face-smile.svg" /></td></tr>
       <tr><td>Active Directory</td></tr>
   </table>
>
```

commandline:

```
dot -Tdot myfile.gv|gvpr -c -f moveLabel.gvpr | neato -n2 -Tsvg >myfile.svg
```

moveLable.gvpr:

```
BEGIN{
  string saveLbl, saveX, saveY, workS;
  graph_t theG;
  node_t newNode;
}
BEG_G{
  print("// ONE");
  theG=subg($G, "cluster_IT_outcome");
  saveLbl=theG.label;
  // next 3 steps get the left X coordinate of the cluster
  workS=llOf(theG.bb);
  workS=xOf(workS);
  saveX=(float)workS;
  // now get Y coordinate of label
  workS=yOf(theG.lp);
  saveY=(float)workS;
  theG.label="";     // remove label from cluster
}
END_G{  
  // create new node to replace cluster label
  newNode=node($G, "__myNewNode");
  newNode.pos=sprintf("%.2f,%.2f", saveX, saveY);
  newNode.shape="plain";
  newNode.fillcolor="none";
  newNode.label=html($G, saveLbl);
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it. Awesome solution. It worked